# TypeError: e is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Good day.

When running my app i get the following error related to my `vue-router:`

> TypeError: e is not a function

however i have nothing ... i simply named "e" in my code.

I have a few before each options but nothing too big besides a few cookies deletions.

I have a few imports of apps and i am trying to use them in my router and they all work. So does the cookies. I did the `beforeEach()` method a few times to see if the error was there but so far no luck.

i got no idea of what is going on.

EDIT: When trying to figure this i was comenting on my code to see if i could find the error and when i removed most of the `beforeEach()` section i left on the `next()` function and a new error showed sayin "t is not a function", so i guess for some reason java script is only recognizing the last letters of my funcions, like t in next() and e in some().

EDIT2: After removing unecessary code that i copied from another project apperently the error happens in my next() function.

here's my router code:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Dashboard from "@/views/Dashboard.vue";
import Opcoes from "@/views/settings.vue";
import LoginForm from "@/components/component/loginForm.vue";
import store from "./store.js";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

Vue.use(Router);

let router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "loginForm",
      component: LoginForm,
      meta: {
        guest: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "Dashboard",
      component: Dashboard,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/opcoes",
      name: "Opcoes",
      component: Opcoes,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/sair",
      name: "Sair",
      component: LoginForm,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {


 const expirationDate = Cookies.get("expireIn");
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  if (now >= expirationDate) {
    Cookies.remove("expirationDate");
    Cookies.remove("token");
    Cookies.remove("userId");
    store.dispatch('LOGOUT');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Heres a print of my stack trace:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196497/discussion-on-question-by-otorrinolaringologista-man-typeerror-e-is-not-a-func).

Answer (score 1):

## My Big Fat Guess

The error message points to line 2203 (line 1921 is part of a generic error handler). This line is in the Router `push()` method

```js
onComplete && onComplete(route);
```

My guess is, somewhere in your code not shown in your question (perhaps in your `LoginForm` component), you are calling `this.$router.push()` with a second argument that is **not** a function, eg

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'Dashboard' }, somethingNotAFunction)
```

#### Other problems (from previous versions of the question)

Your `/` route (*loginForm*) has no params so this...

```js
next({
  path: "/",
  params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
});
```

is invalid. Did you perhaps mean to send `nextUrl` as a query parameter. If so, use

```js
next({ name: 'loginForm', query: { nextUrl: to.fullPath } })
```

---

You also have

```js
next({ path: "login" });
```

and

```js
next({ name: "login" });
```

neither of which exist in your routes. You should only forward the route request to existing routes.

---

Finally, if you're using Vuex, you should not be directly assigning state values. In [strict-mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html), this

```js
store.state.isLoggedIn = false
```

will trigger an error. You should be committing state mutations instead.

Comment: ok so ill look into each one of those. i removed all the unecessary next() methods and now i only have a single one of them, right after my first if inside an else. however the error still persists. as for the mutation ill do just that with a dispatch.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man what versions of Vue (the dependency, **not** the CLI) and vue-router are you using?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man could you please update your question with the minimal code you currently have?

Comment: Aperently the error still occurs in my next() function for some reason

Comment: A stack trace should probably elucidate the mystery.

Comment: i am kind of a newbie here, how di i stack trace?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man refer to those screenshots I asked you for earlier

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I think you missed my comment above asking for the versions of Vue and vue-router. Please provide those

Comment: my vue version is 3.8.2

Comment: my vue-router is 3.0.6

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man and that's specifically why I said _"**not** the CLI"_. Vue 3 is not even out of planning stage yet. What is your vue and and vue-router dependency versions?

Comment: i used vue --version to check it. hwo do i check only my vue version?

Comment: It will be listed in `package.json`

Comment: in my json i found the following:
"vue": {
      "version": "2.6.10",

Comment: i dont think i can send  a screenshot since the company network blocks most image uploader sites

Comment: well what you suggested didnt work but thanks anyways mate

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my error!

Answer (score 0):

If this problem persists try to disable Vue Devtools extension. I had the same thing and disabling devtools extension works for me.